# How does GCP internal load balancer + GKE service work? (It works, but I do not know why)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, istio, gke-networking, gcp-load-balancer

E.g.  an istio service

```
istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   10.103.19.83   10.160.32.41   15021:30943/TCP,80:32609/TCP,443:30341/TCP,3306:30682/TCP,15443:30302/TCP
```

Which resulted in a TCP internal load balancer. The front end is ports 15021, 80, 443, 3306, and 15443.

The backend is basically the instance group of the cluster.

How does the load balancer know 443 at the front end will forward to 30341 at backend? As far as I know, TCP load balancer is doing port forwarding? How/Where does the magic happening

Comment: You still need the answer to this question or you already know?

Answer (score 1):

When a `Service` is created in **kubernetes**, a corresponding `Endpoints` object is created along with it. It also applies to `LoadBalancer` service type.

If you [create a simple nginx deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-stateless-application-deployment/#creating-and-exploring-an-nginx-deployment) e.g. by running:

```
kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/application/deployment.yaml
```

and then expose it as a `LoadBalancer` service:

```
kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/application/deployment.yaml
```

apart from the service itself, you will also see the `lb-nginx` `Endpoints` object. You can inspect its details:

kubectl get ep lb-nginx -o yaml

As you can see it keeps track of all exposed pods (being part of a `Deployment` in this case) so that corresponding **iptables** rules, which are responsible for forwarding the traffic to a particular pod, can be up-to-date all the time, even if number of them or their ip chages.

You can e.g. scale your deployment to 5 replicas:

```
kubectl scale deployment nginx-deployment --replicas=5
```

and inspect the `Endpoints` object again:

```
kubectl get ep lb-nginx -o yaml
```

and you will see that right after your 5 pods are up and running it immediately gets updated as well.

As you can see in `subsets` section of the yaml:

```
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: 10.12.0.3
    nodeName: gke-gke-default-pool-75259266-oauz
    targetRef:
      kind: Pod
      name: nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5-dw9mt
      namespace: default
      resourceVersion: "22394113"
      uid: 8d7e1d3e-64e2-4891-b567-61ee48f61ed1
```

apart from the ip address of the `Pod` it maintains information about the node on which it is running.

Let's go back for a moment to the `Service`:

```
kubectl get svc lb-nginx -o yaml
```

As you can see `LoadBalancer` service apart from its external IP address has its `ClusterIP` as every other `Service` (well, almost every as headless services don't have ClusterIP):

```
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.16.6.236
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.16.6.236
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - nodePort: 31935
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
```

So as you can imagine this external IP is somehow mapped to the cluster ip so it route the traffic further to the respective endpoints in the cluster. How exactly this mapping is done doesn't really matter as it is done by the cloud provider and such implementation details are not part of publicly shared knowledge. The only thing you need to know is that when your cloud provider provisions an external load balancer to satisfy your request defined in a `Service` of `LoadBalancer` type, apart from creating an external load balancer it takes care of the mapping between this external IP and some standard port assigned to it and a kubernetes service which has all the information needed to route the traffic further to the respective pods. In case you wonder how exactly this is done on GCP side i.e. mapping/binding between the external (or internal) loadbalancer and kubernetes `LoadBalancer` service, I'm affraid such implementation details are not publicly revealed.

Answer (score 0):

The LoadBalancer Service type is an extension of the NodePort type, which is an extension of the ClusterIP type. A nodePort just opens up a port in the range 30000-32767 on each worker node and uses a label selector to identify which Pods to send the traffic to.

This means that internal clients call the Service by using the internal IP address of a node along with the TCP port specified by nodePort. The request is forwarded to one of the member Pods on the TCP port specified by the targetPort field.

Here’s an [example](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/service#services_of_type_loadbalancer)